# Matrices with different size element-by-element comparison

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, bsxfun

I have two matrices, but with different size.
Right now I'm doing the comparison like this:

```
ABV = zeros(5,5);
ABB = zeros(4,1);
for ii = 1:4
    test = ABV > ABB(ii)
end
```

I'm trying to find a vectorized method that would do the same thing, as my matrices are not that small. I tried to use `BSXFUN`, however it asks for same dimension matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) there to "send" the elements of `ABB` to the `third dimension` creating `singleton dimensions` in `dim-1` and `dim-2`. Thus, the final result after applying `bsxfun` (for singleton expansion) would be an expanded `3D array` covering the comparisons for each element of the 2D array `ABV` against each element of 1D array `ABB`. So, do something like this -

```
test = bsxfun(@gt,ABV,permute(ABB(:),[3 2 1]))
```

Thus, each 3D slice of `test` would be the comparison of all elements of `ABV` against one of the elements in `ABB`.

---

Since `ABB` is a 1D array, you can replace `permute` with [`reshape`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) -

```
test = bsxfun(@gt,ABV,reshape(ABB,1,1,[]))
```

---

You can avoid using `bsxfun` at the third dimension by converting the input 2D array to a 1D array and this might lead to a more efficient approach as listed here -

```
test = reshape(bsxfun(@gt,ABV(:),ABB(:).'),[size(ABV) numel(ABB)])
```